# How can I optimize PySpark code to compare a list of IDs with 2 billion rows of data split into 1000 Parquet files stored in Azure Blob storage?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, parquet, azure-synapse-analytics

I have about 2 billion rows of data stored in my blob storage. Each row has following schema

| ID | Column A | ..... | Column AZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345235 | Detail | ..... | Details.. |
| 783566 | Detail | ..... | Details.. |

I have split this data into 1000 parquet files and stored in a azure blob container. There is a new file created everyday.
I have got a list of 100 IDs (123,456,678...) and I want to compare it against the IDs in each file and remove those id's from the respective file. These selected id's should be removed from every file without changing name, folder or other contents of the parquet file.

Considering the volume of data what would be the best way to do this operation. This operation is to be done daily so I am looking for an efficient way to do this in **pyspark**.

Note: Every day the list of id's keep changing. I am using **pyspark** in azure synapse analytics.

I have tried looping through each file and it is a resource intensive process.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I see many issues with your process:

1. Why split 2 billion rows in 1000 files? You should split your data according to file size, 1000 files sounds like a lot. Are all files the same size? If yes, how many KB is that?
2. If you don't want to iterate over every file, spark can integrate them all at once, but unless you are using a partitioned table system, the file names and folders will be edited.
3. How are you comparing the IDs? Are you doing a join? Because 100 IDs is small enough that you could simply run a query with "WHERE ids in ({ids_to_insert})".

Comment: I am running an ETL process that loads the data for the day in a new file. I have data for about 1000 days now. So thats how I have soo many files.
2023-->5-->25>2023525.parquet.